# Talend studio export/import jobs from version 6.4 and 5.6.1

Tags: import, export, talend

I have successfully imported talend project from version 5.6.1 into version 6.4, but generated .bat scripts don't work out of the box, meaning .bat script produced by talend studio 5.6.1 and talend studio 6.4 are different.
One ugly hack is to make jobs in talend studio 6.4 and with export/import open in talend studio 5.6.1 and build the job. But I can't import talend jobs made in 6.4 into 5.6.1 even with one tMap component.
Any solution ?

Comment: What doesn't work in the bat?

Comment: For ex. if you override only one parameter, every other parameter is with empty string like --context PARAM1="" --context PARAM2="" etc

Comment: Might this be relevant for the bug tracker of Talend?